# Does sudo dnf install dnf-plugins-core -y affect all users?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

I'm a newbie to Fedora and a novice at Linux in general, but I just want to know whether I have to run that command in every different user account: I have three, a root user, and two others for some people who borrow my computer. I don't want to do this more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to run that command for every user. The [Core DNF plugins](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf-plugins-core) (documentation [here](https://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) are installed system-wide. You need only install them once, as the root user.